# Como atualizar conteúdo do arquivo javascript na página?

Tags: javascript, .net

Pesquisei no fórum e não encontrei uma solução definitiva, meu problema é com relação a cachê de navegador, quando faço uma alteração em um arquivo javascript, meu cliente só recebe o arquivo atualizado após a limpeza do cachê.

Já tratamos conforme código abaixo:

`<script src='<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/MeuJavaScript.js?sid=" + Session.SessionID) %>`

Onde concatenamos a sessão do usuário ao link do arquivo, porém, mesmo com isso o arquivo permanece desatualizado.

Obrigado.

Comment: Já tentou utilizar ao invés da Session.SessionID, forçar alguma outra concatenação qualquer só pra ver se atualiza? Sei lá, coloca um número aleatório na frente e ve se atualiza.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode configurar o navegador através da tag meta para não salvar na cache o conteúdo do seu site, desta forma:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

**Update**

Você pode fazer no inicio do seu script uma requisição ajax para conferir a versão no seu servidor, assim toda vez que ele atualizar você executa o comando:

```
window.location.reload(true)
```

Ou envia uma mensagem para o usuário informando sobre o novo script.